# Starting node server, do something else, and terminating server on Gitlab CI

Tags: batch-file, npm, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a shell gitlab runner setup and I have the following gitlab-ci.yml file, in beforescript it installs necessary packages and starts the node server, I have to use "start npm run start" here because otherwise it will just stay forever at "server started at xxxxxxx". When I use this, it successfully terminates the node.exe processes, but after that happens it just hangs there forever and I have to manually cancel the build, and it never runs the after_script section.

```
Test:
  before_script:
    - call npm install
    - start npm run start
  script:
   - waitfor SomethingThatIsNeverHappening /t 3 & taskkill /t /f /im node.exe & exit 0
  after_script:
    - echo HELLLLLLLLLLO
```

My question is how would one go about doing something like this? I want to have this exact code where I start the server, do something, and then terminate the server, but after this happens it should terminate the build successfully and show the proper status like failed/passed on gitlab. Right now it does everything in the file but after everything is done the app just hangs forever, instead of terminating and showing success. If I have no after_script section this will still hang forever at the end.

Note: I have tried exit 0 and exit 1 and they don't do anything.

Relevant Log:

```
$ start npm run start

$ waitfor SomethingThatIsNeverHappening /t 3 & taskkill /t /f /im node.exe & exit 0

ERROR: Timed out waiting for 'SomethingThatIsNeverHappening'.

SUCCESS: The process with PID 2396 (child process of PID 9196) has been terminated.

SUCCESS: The process with PID 10040 (child process of PID 9196) has been terminated.

SUCCESS: The process with PID 8452 (child process of PID 9196) has been terminated.

SUCCESS: The process with PID 11172 (child process of PID 9196) has been terminated.

SUCCESS: The process with PID 5416 (child process of PID 9196) has been terminated.

SUCCESS: The process with PID 9196 (child process of PID 8648) has been terminated.

SUCCESS: The process with PID 8648 (child process of PID 8272) has been terminated.

SUCCESS: The process with PID 8272 (child process of PID 8512) has been terminated.
```

After this point it just keeps running forever without another line of new output

Comment: Is this an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)?  Exactly what are you trying do?  Running taskkill in a build script seems a bit crude.  What do you think `start npm run start` does?  Was there any log output? Please post it.

Comment: I'm trying to run npm run start, do something else, and then terminate that server afterwards and have my gitlab-ci build also terminate. start npm run start opens a new window for npm run start and lets me do other things in the console while the server is running. the issue is the build never stops, it runs the last command under script and hangs there forever

Comment: Do you ever exit the console instance created by running start?

Comment: BTW I get an error when I execute `npm run start`.

Comment: I do, by taskkilling node.exe. After terminating it I can try to access my server on that computer and it will not be accessible, because its been terminated. But it seems like the gitlab runner doesn't know that its been terminated since it just stays up. start is just the name i have given my script, it could be called xxx and I would start it with npm start xxx

Comment: I suspect that killing node.exe does not kill the console session you started from it.  Try adding `/t` option.

Comment: I just tried that and it did not work, I have also attached log, but it doesn't really say much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208674/discussion-between-jwdonahue-and-meshier).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by using powershell as my shell of choice, specified in the config.toml file in the runner folder. After converting the commands over to powershell friendly commands, everything worked out fine.